How do I use conditional compiler commands in VBA to define objects (recordsets) conditionally?
I have a Windows app that I'm upgrading so that my Mac users can also use it. The trick is that it accesses an SQL Server backend. On Windows, I can use the ADODB library, but I knew that ADO wouldn't work on the Mac. I'm testing an ODBC driver from ActualTech. I'm using conditional compiling to separate the two methods to submit the SQL statement. But I'm seeing a message for this code in my Declarations section when I run this on the Mac.
#If (Win32 Or Win64) Then
Global rst As ADODB.Recordset
Global cnn As ADODB.Connection
#Else
#End If

The error I'm getting is "Can't find project or library" and the line with the problem is the Global rat line.
I know that the ADODB library doesn't work on the Mac, which is why I tried to put it into a conditional compiling block. Am I doing something wrong, or does conditional compiling not work in the Declarations section?
I've tried another method -- to set the rst object within a routine and then to pass it to a routine just for Windows, and I'll call a Mac-specific routine for Mac users. I'm using the compiler commands to set off the routine by putting them around the entire routine.
#If (Win32 Or Win64) Then
Sub Add_costs_win(rst As Recordset, RiskID As String, Version_number As Integer)
'     Code to execute goes here
End Sub
#End If

but running the app on the Mac flags the rst parameter with a compile error that it can't find the library, even though the Mac will never call this routine.
How can I include a recordset object in code that has to compile on the Mac? Or am I going to have to create and support two identical versions of the app except for the database calls?
I tried using the conditional compile commands to keep the Mac from trying to compile the sections of code that reference the recordset. I tried hiding the Global definition of the object in the Declarations section.
I also tried putting the subroutine that receives the recordset as an object inside the conditional compile block to try and prevent the Mac from trying to compile that routine, but it still gave the library error.
I searched for an answer using VBA, Conditional Compiler, Declarations. I got lots of hits on conditional compile and lots of hits on DECLARE but none that put the two together.
I think I mis-identified the problem. I converted to late-binding as suggested and still had errors -- and I doubted that the conditional directives were performing correctly. I wrote this code as a test.
Sub MyTest ()

    #If Win16 then
        MsgBox "Win16"
    #End If
    
    #If Win32 then
        MsgBox "Win32"
    #End If
    
    #If Win32 then
        MsgBox "Win32"
    #End If
    
    #If Mac then
        MsgBox "Mac"
    #End If End Sub
    
    #If Not Mac then
        MsgBox "Win"
    #End If

End Sub

I'm running on a [64-bit] MacBook Pro & on 64-bit Win (Windows 10 Enterprise) & surprised by results of the conditional directives.
On the Windows laptop, I see the messages for Win32 and Win.

On the Mac, I see the messages for Win64, Mac, and Win.

Have you tried using late binding like Global rst As Object ?

Note according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/compiler-constants Win32 is True in both 32- and 64-bit environments

Tim, that is a terrific idea that I didn’t think of — I don’t normally use late binding.
So I can define rst as an object in the Declaration and then specify it as an ADODB.Recordset in the code? Would I put the references to the recordset object inside the conditional compiler statements still?

I don't have a Mac, but if (in a workbook without a reference to the ADO library) I put Global rs As adodb.Recordset inside a conditional compile using #If Mac Then, it doesn't get flagged up as "can't find project or library" unless I swap to #If Win32 Then

@TimWilliams That's what I expected; I was surprised to get an error inside the condit compile section on the Mac.
Maybe I mis-identified the problem.
I just changed everything to late-binding and I have a different error. It seems like it's ignoring the conditional compiler on the Mac. I have
#If (Win16 or Win32) then
msgbox "hi"
and I see the dialog box.
Same thing if I change the compiler test to
#if Not Mac then
MsgBox "Hi"
and I'm running it on the Mac, and it's giving me a dialog box.
And I changed it to
#If Not Mac then
MsgBox "Hi"
and it still processes.

Work OK for me on Windows - sorry I don't have any ideas for what's happening on Mac.

Maybe take a look here also - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/that-whacky-conditional-compiler-constant/3da810b8-9b89-4372-8104-a10c2ad25d4d#:~:text=Why%20Is%20The%20Faulty%20Boolean%20Test%20An%20Issue%3F

"Don’t use the “Not” operator when working with built-in constants. Rather, use the “#Else” clause"   https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/that-whacky-conditional-compiler-constant/3da810b8-9b89-4372-8104-a10c2ad25d4d#:~:text=Don%E2%80%99t%20use%20the%20%E2%80%9CNot%E2%80%9D%20operator%20when%20working%20with%20built%2Din%20constants.%20Rather%2C%20use%20the%20%E2%80%9C%23Else%E2%80%9D%20clause%3A
